# Modify EF Core Insert and Update statements

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

How can I modify the generated INSERT and UPDATE statements in EF Core?

I would like to add some ids, ideally as a SQL comment:

```sql
UPDATE Task SET Name = 'Test' WHERE Id = 1
    -- correlationId: abcde12345
```

In queries, I can do something similar with Linq:

```
var queryInternal = dbContext.Set<Task>().Where(t => t.Id == 1);
queryInternal.Where(e => correlationId == correlationId);
```

which will generate a query containing my correlation id, without affecting the result:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Task WHERE Id = 1 AND 'abcde12345' = 'abcde12345'
```

**What I tried:**

I have access to the changed entities before calling `SaveChanges()`. So I tried setting the values there.

```
var changes = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries;
foreach (var item in changes)
{
    item.Property("correlationId").CurrentValue = correlationId;
}
```

But this requires an actual property on the model and a column in the database.

Is there any other way of adding some arbitrary values to the INSERT and UPDATE statements without affecting the result?

Comment: You can try `.Where(t => t.Id == 1 && t.correlationId == correlationId)`

Comment: Or use `vat x = GetAll().Where(t => t.Id == 1 && t.correlationId == correlationId)` and set  properties of x and then call `Update` method

Comment: Hi @viveknuna, that both works for queries, which I managed. But I am looking for a way to do the same thing with SaveChanges(), in which case the WHERE clause only contains the Id property.

Comment: I didn't get you. My comments solved your problem?

Comment: Are you asking if you can just throw a new column value into a table, and then make SQL alter the table and generate the column to fit the new value?

I don't follow what you are asking. Could you try rephrasing?

Or are you asking if you can simply modify the query to have multiple values in them? like dbContext.Set<Task>.Where(t => t.id == 1 && t.correlationId == correlationId) because that works just fine?

Comment: Hi @MortenBork, I am trying to have values in the insert and update commands generated by SaveChanges() that are not values in columns. I use the EF Command Logging to log the commands, but I have no state in the logger. So I need to pass the correlation information in the command somehow. That works fine with queries, where I can just query for arbitrary values which don't need to be columns. I am trying to do the same with the commands. Does that make it clearer? Thanks

Comment: @viveknuna unfortunately it doesn't. The code in your comment works well with queries, but not with the commands generated by SaveChanges().

Comment: Why do you need `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: We use SaveChanges() to create and execute the insert and update commands.

Comment: This is how we use the EF Command Logging, based on the .NET Logger Factory: https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/entity-framework-core-and-linq-to-entities-3-logging-and-tracing-queries But since it runs asynchronously, I have no other way of passing the state from the moment we call SaveChanges() to the moment the command is logged.

Comment: No it still doesn't make it clearer to me. 

It sounds like you are trying to update a column that isn't there. Which ... doesn't make any sense?

Comment: No, I am trying to add state or meta-information to the command, so that I can relate the command to a request, for example. In a query I can do that because I can always add arbitrary text to the query, for example AND 'a' = 'a' will not alter the result of the query, but I have the state 'a' in the query. I am trying to do the same with update and insert commands.

Comment: @SebastianRösch Maybe you can inherit from `DatabaseLogFormatter` and process everything there? Maybe you can alter `DbCommand` parameter, I am not sure.

Comment: Check [EF Core interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) you can modify SQL commands even in advanced scenarios.